# Java 8 Functional Programming - Need to write a generic function on class

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, producer-consumer

I want to create a method that accepts something like this

```
set(nodeStatus, status, NodeStatus::setStatus, Status::valueOf);
set(nodeStatus, errorCode, NodeStatus::setErrorCode, ErrorCode::valueOf);
```

Status and ErrorCode are enums in java.

Signature and pseudocode

```
set(NodeStatus nodeStatus, byte[] status, ?nodeStatusOperator , ?ValueTransformer) {
   1. convert byte[] status to appropriate value as per ValueTransformer
   2. nodeStatusOperator sets this transformed value according to the lambda passed.
}
```

I want to know what method signature should be used to accompalish this in java and why. I tried various Consumers, BiConsumers etc but couldnt do this. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, what you need is this:

```
public <T> void set (NodeStatus nodeStatus, 
                     byte [] value, 
                     BiConsumer<NodeStatus,T> setter, 
                     Function<byte[],T> transformer) {
    T transformedValue = transformer.apply(value);
    setter.accept(nodeStatus, transformedValue);
}
```

(If `value` can be something other than `byte[]`, you can replace it with another type parameter.)

P.s.: `setter` is a `BiConsumer`, because you use a static method reference (e.g. `NodeStatus::setErrorCode`) on an instance method, so the first argument of `BiConsumer` has to be the `NodeStatus` instance `setErrorCode()` will be called on.

P.p.s: As pointed out by [glglgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296974/glglgl), you can potentially simplify your code to this:

```
public <T> void set (byte [] value, 
                     Consumer<T> setter, 
                     Function<byte[],T> transformer) {
    T transformedValue = transformer.apply(value);
    setter.accept(transformedValue);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
set(status, nodeStatus::setStatus, Status::valueOf);
```

...where `nodeStatus` is the instance of `NodeStatus` you want to manipulate.

Comment: OP didn't specify if that's allowed for him, but if so, I'd refine this to `public <T> void set (byte [] value, 
                     Consumer<T> setter, 
                     Function<byte[],T> transformer) {
        T transformedValue = transformer.apply(value);
        setter.accept(transformedValue);
    }
`, including the status object into the setter method reference. The calls then be like `set(status, nodeStatus::setStatus, Status::valueOf);
    set(errorCode, nodeStatus::setErrorCode, ErrorCode::valueOf);`

Comment: @glglgl You're absolutely right, that would look a lot cleaner. I just went with the signature OP provided, but I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone - Such a quick response and excellent use of generics

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you're trying to achieve. Why pass the NodeStatus and the function when you could just pass a function that works on that specific NodeStatus instance, e.g.:

```
static <T> void set(byte[] status, Consumer<T> nodeStatusOperator, Function<String, T> transformer) {
    nodeStatusOperator.accept(transformer.apply(new String(status)));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    NodeStatus nodeStatus = new NodeStatus();
    byte[] status = new byte[0];
    set(status, nodeStatus::setStatus, Status::valueOf);
    set(status, nodeStatus::setErrorCode, ErrorCode::valueOf);
}
```

And what does that genericity buy you over a more straightforward approach?

```
nodeStatus.setStatus(Status.valueOf(new String(status)));
nodeStatus.setErrorCode(ErrorCode.valueOf(new String(status)));
```

Comment: new String(status) is common for all Enums. Similarly in my class there are multiple other setters like Date where conversion is different. Also there are string setters. Moreover I can apply some general checks on the transformed value for multiple setters of same type and thus reduce line of code. Example: nodeStatus.setUpdateTs(new Date(BinaryUtils.bytesToLong(updateTs))